# Tried to import a local font but it's not working

Tags: html, css, fonts

so I'm trying to import a local font, but for some reason it's not being recognized, can I get some quick help on where I'm going wrong please?

I currently have 3 documents: index page, stylesheet.css and fonts.css.
I'm trying to use the font 'cinzel' however it's not working.

Index page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="fonts" type="text/css" href="css/fonts/fonts.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet/stylesheet.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">



    </style>
    <title>
        RENTDrive
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> RENTDrive </h1>

    <hr>


    <h3> Lots of exotic cars to choose from</h3>
    <a href="fleet.html">Book your vehicle now!</a> <p> Terms and conditions apply</p>
</body>
```

stylesheet.css page:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'cinzel';
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'cinzel';
}
```

And the fonts.css page:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'cinzel';
    src: url('css/fonts/Cinzel-Regular.otf') format('opentype'),
         url('css/fonts/CinzelDecorative-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Check your console to see if you have any errors.

Comment: no errors that I can see... got unexpected token on line 1 but it looks fine to me..

Comment: That sounds like an error.

Comment: But I can't change it, there's nothing to change here...

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the rel to stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fonts/fonts.css"/>
```

Comment: Tried this. Does not change anything.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: Just to rule it out I would check the network tab to make sure the css file is being pulled.  In the body when h1 is hit it should try to get the otf.

Answer (score 0):

heading tag's default font-weight is bold(in user agent stylesheet).
so, you will remove `font-weight: normal`, you can see that